# SQL to Linq select multiple columns in group by

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I would like to convert a SQL statement to LINQ but i have some problems doing it.

The sql statement is :

```
SELECT 
    C.[Call_Date], CC.[Company], R.Resolution, 
    COUNT_BIG(*) AS CNT,
    SUM([Duration]) AS Total
FROM 
    [Calls] C
Join 
    [CompanyCharges] CC on [Company_Charge] = [CompanyCharge] 
Join 
    [Resolutions] R on C.Call_Resolution = R.Resolution
where 
    Call_Date >= '05/29/2013' 
Group By 
    C.[Call_Date], CC.[Company], CC.[CompanyCharge], R.Resolution, R.Resolution_Order
```

I wrote something like :

```
var stats = from c in dbContext.Calls
    join cc in dbContext.CompanyCharges on c.Company_Charge equals cc.CompanyCharge
    join r in dbContext.Resolutions on c.Call_Resolution equals r.Resolution
    where (c.Call_Date > "05/29/2013")
    group new { c, cc, r } by new { c.Call_Date, cc.CompanyCharge, r.Resolution, r.Resolution_Order } into statsGroup
    select new { Count = statsGroup.Count(), ??? };
```

I managed to count the elements, but i need a sum[duration] and some columns from different tables. 
Please share your wisdome with me.

Comment: To convert a SQL query to a LINQ one, you can use a tool such as Linqer: http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: I want to learn LINQ by solving my problems. When i cannot i write here on SO and try to learn from the answers i receive. I don't want to use a tool. Thanks anyway. `Linqer is on SALE`

Comment: The tool does contain the knowledge you seek. Would you say it's fair to assume that, if the tool showed you how to convert your SQL query to LINQ, you would learn from that as much as you would learn from an answer here?

Comment: I end up installing Linqer. Thanks for your idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the `[Duration]` field is part of the `[Calls]` table:

```
var stats = /* ... */
    select new 
    { 
        Count = statsGroup.Count(), 
        Total = statsGroup.Sum(stat => stat.c.Duration),
    };
```

You'd probably want to include your grouping fields in the new anonymous type as well:

```
var stats = /* ... */
    select new 
    { 
        Call_Date = statsGroup.Key.c.Call_Date,
        CompanyCharge = statsGroup.Key.cc.CompanyCharge, 
        Resolution = statsGroup.Key.r.Resolution, 
        Count = statsGroup.Count(), 
        Total = statsGroup.Sum(stat => stat.c.Duration),
    };
```

Comment: Seems like you missed **Key** property after **statsGroup** (statsGroup.Key.c.Call_Date, statsGroup.Key.cc.CompanyCharge, statsGroup.Key.r.Resolution)

Comment: `select new{ g.Key.Call_Date, g.Key.Company, g.Key.Resolution, CNT = g.Count(), Total = (int?)g.Sum(p => p.C.Duration)}` This the answer i was looking forward. @Douglas : please edit your answer to be correct and i will accept it.

Comment: @rhose87: Why `int?`? I don't believe `Total` was nullable in the SQL code?

Comment: Linqer convert it that way. I used just `int`.